# Resupply Credentials to Printer Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, active-directory, credentials

I'm working on my personal laptop and attach to various drives, machines, printers, etc. as needed.   I'm NOT connected directly to the domain.

Due to password change restrictions, I do not let it store my password, instead I reauthorize each time I need a resource (not that big a deal really).

Our passwords change every 90 days and I had a situation where the printer kept trying to reconnect with the old stored password.  After 5 fails, my account would lock out and I'd have to visit IT Support.  Lots of fun.

Every other resource lets me respecify the credentials when I want to map to it.  \SERVER\SHARE and it prompts me.

However, when I add a printer, I give my credentials and tell it not to save them.  Works fine UNTIL a reboot.  Then the printer is still there just fine and I can print to it, however all documents are just "pending" because the printer is "offline".

How can I take an existing printer and resupply the credentials so that it will come back online?  Deleting the printer and re-adding it is WAY overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...

Quite simple really

```
net use \\server\printer password /user:domain\userid
```

I put that into a batch file and then can just run it.

I can also add it via PowerShell, but that's another story... :)

Answer (score 1):

My passwords also change every 90 days, and the only passwords that I let Windows store are for printers. File shares use my Windows (domain) credentials, and web sites auto-enter my credentials via [`lastpass.com`](http://www.lastpass.com). (I never let IE {a.k.a., Internet Exploder} store passwords.)

I suggest letting Windows store your printer passwords.